# Calling a method from a namespace to use in another javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

To organize my code, I happened to write as namespace for my main javascript file. Then I want to call some of the functions of that file to my custom javascript file, let say `script.js`. The problem is that I couldn't access the methods of the namespace. Here is my example code:

**main.js**

```
$( function() {
    "use strict"
     var Accordian = {
     slide : function() {
         $('h3').click( function() {
             $(this).next('div').slideToggle('1000');
             $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
         });
    },

    slideEaseOutBounce: function() {
         $('h3').click( function() {
              $(this).next().animate(
                  {'height' : 'toggle'}, 1000, 'easeOutBounce'
               );
               $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
         });
    },

    slideEaseInOutExpo: function() {
         $('h3').click( function() {
             $(this).next().animate(
                  {'height' : 'toggle'}, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo'
             );
             $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
         });
    }
});
```

And I have tried as in below **script.js**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    Accordian.slide();
});
```

**UPDATED:**

Here's the link:
http://jsnamespace.comyr.com/using-accordian.html

And the error message occurs `"ReferenceError: Accordian is not defined"`
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: When I try and access the site I get the following, followed by some parking ads: **This website was set to be removed for inactivity by www.000webhost.com. If you own this website, click here to protect it.**  About your question, are you simply referencing both scripts in your HTML file or is there another method that you're using?

Comment: Ah, this link is just removed. I added 3 days ago. I'll uploaded it again. Here it works again. http://jsnamespace.comyr.com/using-accordian.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: `line 63` is missing a semicolon in `script.js`.

Since modifying your site to use this code works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        Accordian[0].slide();
    });
</script>
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BUpQf/)

it seems that wrapping your "Accoridian" inside the jQuery function requires it to be dereferenced as a sub element.

When you remove the `$` at `line 1` of `script.js` turning

```
var Accordian = $(function () {
```

into

```
var Accordian = (function () {
```

(like @anonyme suggested) [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/BUpQf/1/) with your original call to `Accordian.slide()`.

Answer (score 3):

first you have to make a unique root namespace like that :

```
window.Accordian = window.Accordian || {};
```

This part must be done on top of all the next !
it Can be done in the head of html page in a script tag.

after you can use your object :

```
//creating a function :
Accordian.slide = function() {
     $('h3').click( function() {
         $(this).next('div').slideToggle('1000');
         $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
     });
}

//and later using it :
Accordian.slide()
```

This is the simplest way !

You prefered using multiple file, so let's try :

**mains.js**

```
/*$*/( function(globalAccordian) {
    "use strict"
     /* var Accordian = { */
     globalAccordian = {
     // doing like this will override your globalAccordian
     // if it was already generated by another script
     slide : function() {
         $('h3').click( function() {
             $(this).next('div').slideToggle('1000');
             $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
         });
    },

    slideEaseOutBounce: function() {
         $('h3').click( function() {
              $(this).next().animate(
                  {'height' : 'toggle'}, 1000, 'easeOutBounce'
               );
               $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
         });
    },

    slideEaseInOutExpo: function() {
         $('h3').click( function() {
             $(this).next().animate(
                  {'height' : 'toggle'}, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo'
             );
             $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
         });
    }
})( window.Accordian || {} );
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    Accordian.slide();
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still does not work. Here's my link to the test http://jsnamespace.comyr.com/using-accordian.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the namespace because it is encapsulated in a function. 
I'd suggest reading up on the [revealing module pattern](http://blog.davidlitmark.com/post/6009004931/an-introduction-to-the-revealing-module-pattern).

JSFiddle: 
     http://jsfiddle.net/R927K/

Example:

```
    var Accordian = (function() {

     var Accordian = {
     slide : function() {
         alert('sliding');
         }
     };

         return Accordian;
}());

Accordian.slide();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how could I access its method to my script.js file?

Comment: Just as you did in your example ( I hope, if I am correct :) ).

Comment: Assumg both main.js and script.js are properly loaded into the page ofcourse.

Comment: I didn't get it work actually, I tried `Acordian.slide()` and it says 'TypeError: Acordian.slide is not a function', then I tried `Acordian.slide` and nothing happens with no error message and the action itself.

Comment: Sorry, was too quick with my answer. Check the updated answer with a working JSFiddle.

Comment: Yah, it works when I call it from the same `main.js` file, but it doesn't when I call it from my `script.js`. Note that I already tried this but it did not work. So is there another way to do this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30811/discussion-between-tepkenvannkorn-and-soroush-hakami)